# How to search from array values into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

variable contain (14409,14408,14405) from search box.
i want to search each one of them separately in mysql
if it found one of them fetch data, if not ignore it and show massage not exist

```
<form method="POST" class="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="vehiclenum" placeholder="Search Multiple Separate by a Comma (,)">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" Value="Search">
</form>
```

```
<?php
$vehiclenumerr = array();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
  $vehiclenum = $_POST["vehiclenum"];

$exploded=explode(",",$vehiclenum);
$explodedd=implode("','",$exploded) ;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE num_vehicles IN('$explodedd')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$num_query = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num_query > 0) { ?>
<table> 
<tr>
<th>Vehicle num</th>
<th>Description</th>
</tr>

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['num_vehicles']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['desc_vehicles']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php   }   ?>
</table>

<?php 
} else { $vehiclenumerr[] ="Vehicle Number: ".$vehiclenum. " are NOT Exist";}

}

if(!empty($vehiclenumerr)){
foreach ($vehiclenumerr as $error) {
            echo $error; 
            echo "<br>";
        }
}

?>
```

I expect to found table have 2 results for (14409 & 14405)
and down of that note (Vehicle Number: 14408 are NOT Exist)

i got the table success BUT NO notes of not Exist.

Comment: Yikes! You're opening yourself up to SQL injection with code like this. Before going any further I'd strongly advise spending some time getting to grips with safely querying databases in PHP. It would be irresponsible to provide a working solution to a question like this.

Comment: If you want to search for each of them separately, don't use a single `iN('$explodedd')`. Use a `foreach()` loop that searches for each of them separately.

Comment: If when find some but not all of the ID you want to raise error you can always save the ID you fetch in array and later do `array_diff` with the original array (this way you will stick with 1 SQL query and not multiple

Comment: How does the output should look like? what you get right now? what is the output of your query right now? Please post this info and we will help with creating right algorithm.

Comment: **Nathan Dawson** i ignored now security to simplify code to you to understand it. thanks dear .

Comment: **Barmar** that i want to use it. i tried tutorials to solve with it but failed. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: **dWinder** i want search separately each one by hold id for each one

Comment: **Serghei Leonenco** the output table is coming with two results only. after the table should be note for no exist data

Comment: _“i got the table success BUT NO notes of not Exist.”_ - of course you don’t - because you only tried to handle “missing” results in the else branch to the if that checks if the results contained any records.It contains two, because you found 14409 & 14405 - so that else branch does not execute even once.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will helps:

```
  <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <?php if($row['num_vehicles'] && $row['desc_vehicles']): ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['num_vehicles']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['desc_vehicles']; ?></td>
      </tr>
    <?php else: ?>
      <tr>
      <td><?php echo "Not exist" ?></td>
      <td><?php echo "Not exist" ?></td>
      </tr>
    <php endif; ?>
  <?php   }   ?>
```

Or you can delete "Not exis" field.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help
i found a solution, so i share it with you.

```
$vehiclenum = check_input($_POST["vehiclenum"]);
$exploded = explode(",",$vehiclenum); 
$countexploded = count($exploded);
for ($i = 0; $i < $countexploded; $i++) {
  if (!empty($exploded[$i])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicles WHERE num_vehicles='$exploded[$i]'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect_db, $sql);
    $num_query = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($num_query > 0) {
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            // sort results here
       } 
    } else { $vehiclenumerr[] ="Vehicle Number: ".$exploded[$i]. " are NOT Exist";}
  }
}
```

edit: i also add function to protect from sql Injection::

```
function check_input($data){
    $data=trim($data);
    $data=stripcslashes($data);
    $data=htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```